# How to derive this step in a book called Brownian motion calculus?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, soft-question, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

[image]

[image]

How to derive the step  which result in the magnitude of slope of the path in section 1.8.2?

I know it is not the definition itself.

Comment: The jumps in a binomal model are $\pm\sqrt{t}$. And since you are taking the magnitude it should be clear? But if you are asking why are the jumps distributed as such?

Comment: @Chinny84 - How do you sure it is binomial model and why are the jumps distributed as such?

Comment: Because in the limit $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$ then the distribution because normal.

Comment: @Chinny84 - I can't understand it effectively, can you write down a formal answer? Thanks in advance!